# Authorized domain in exchange 2010 would not send email to internet but internally to main domain

Tags: proxy, exchange-2010, dkim

An authorized domain **authorized-domain.tld** in exchange 2010 with main domain **main-domain.tld** would not send email to internet but internally to main domain.

> Reproduced / describde scenario:

1. User opens outlook client 2010 and binds the authorized domain email account e.g.: **authorized-email@authorized-domain.tld**
2. After account loaded and from this account, user then composes an email to **external@somewhere-in-internet.tld** and **internal@main-domain.tld**
3. Then user send the composed email to both email-adresses
4. Lastly user gets only from the email **external@somewhere-in-internet.tld** an **NDR from the NoSpamProxy Gateway** with following code **#550 5.4.4 Unable to relay ##**

I have checked out the NoSpamProxy rules and also the send connectors of exchange 2010 to the internet, but nothing suspect out there.

I suspect a **missing DKIM selector** (could not find one selector for **authorized-domain.tld** on **main-domain.tld** TXT records) that should allow exchange 2010 Server with the main domain **main-domain.tld** to send emails externally as **authorized-domain.tld**, since MX record for **authorized-domain.tld** accordently points to **main-domain.tld**.

Do you have any ideas on this one, am i right or am i missing something tho ?

Thanks for checking out!

Comment: 1. How did you add this authorized domain(***authorized-domain.tld***) to your organization? Is the process like the following? **Add authorized-domain.tld to DNS suffix** -> **Add this domain to accepted domain** -> **Create an email address policy with this domain** -> **Use this domain suffix for your mailbox(Email Address and UPN)**
2. Could you use this authorized domain to successfully send emails to another external email address(e.g. outlook.com, gmail etc.)?

Comment: 3. What're the configurations of your send connector?(If you attach them, please don't forget to alter any sensitive info.)